# Hashmap side by side comparison

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I am trying to find out if there are more occurrences of a "greater" (ASCII value) character than a "lesser" character. I've counted all of the occurrences of each character into a hashmap. I am wondering how I can compare two key values side by side? I basically want this to be like an array where I can compare if hashmap.value[i + 1] > hashmap.value[i].

String ("ssppprr") --> true
String ("sspprrr") --> false

Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!map.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
            map.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
        } else{
            int x = map.get(str.charAt(i));
            map.put(str.charAt(i), ++x);
        }
    }

    for (Entry<Character, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        Character firstLetter = e.getKey();
        Integer firstAvailable = map.get(firstLetter);
        //compare and return false if true
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `HashMap` is *unordered*. Your check requires order. --- Are you comparing counts in the order seen, or counts in alphabetical order of the letter? E.g. what about `sspprrss`? It that 2 vs 2 vs 2 vs 2, or is it 4 vs 2 vs 2, or is it 2 vs 2 vs 4, or something else?

Comment: Why `true` for `"ssppprr"`?  The **"lesser"** character `'p'` occurs 3 times, compared to only 2 occurrences each for the "greater" characters '`r'` and `'s'`.  The `false` result for `"sspprrr"` makes more sense: the "greatest" character `'s'` appears only twice, compared to 3 times for the lesser character `'r'`.

Comment: This would be in the alphabetical order. It seems as though when they are inserted they always end up in alphabetical order (at least with the 10 or so tests I have done). I am trying to compare counts of times the letter is seen. So if R occurs more times then P, the answer would be false.

Comment: @KevinAnderson - The method should compare alphabetically occurrences of each character so the order is pertinent when storing into the hashmap, then after it is store and in order (I may need to do a LinkedHashMap) the comparisons should just be side by side, where if the next value is greater than the current value, the answer is false.

Comment: OK, if we take the counts for  `"ssppprr"` and line them up alphabetically we have  'p' (3), 'r' (2), 's' (2), yes?  The count for 'p', 3, is **not** greater than the count (2) for the next character 'r' (so not `false` here), and the count for 'r' is **not** greater than the count for the next character `s` (so not `false` here). Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Kevin That is correct, we're all good if none of the proceeding characters count exceed one another.

Comment: If you use a `TreeMap`, the `entrySet` method gives you a set that iterates in ascending key order.  With a `HashMap`, you'd have to sort the entry-set by hand because the iteration order is unpredictable.